# GNU Assembler: instruction meaning

Tags: x86, intel, gnu-assembler

This is from x86 disassebly with objdump.

What does this instruction mean? How will the call address be calculated?

```
call   *0x1bc(%eax)
```

In particular, what does asterisk mean here? Does it simply mean **%eax + 0x1bc** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
Branch addresses with immediate or register operands are prefixed with asterisks.

From [this page](http://csiflabs.cs.ucdavis.edu/~ssdavis/50/att-syntax.htm):

> Branch addressing using registers or memory operands must be prefixed by a '*'.